# Issue in setting unique ID in Domino designer

Tags: unique, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotus-formula

I am new to Domino designer and lotus script,

following my [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064521/how-to-save-form-values-to-db-in-domino-designer-by-lotus-script?noredirect=1#comment44511960_28064521),

I have some issue in setting unique ID (for id field in form).

My formula for Id field value :

> `T_List:=@DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; "Local"; "DBintro";"testview"; 1);
>   @If(@IsNewDoc & @Elements(T_List)=0;1;@IsNewDoc & !@IsError(T_List);@Subset(T_List;1) + 1;id)`

I'm having DB in local (nothing shared).

referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532296/how-to-create-an-auto-incrementing-field-in-lotus-domino) an Answer by AndrewB

> Server : Local
>
> DBname : DBintro
>
> view name : testview
>   id - field in the form (which is set when required to save in DB)

Error I'm getting

> Field id ! does not exist

Please help me to get out of this..
Thanks

EDIT :1 Updated code

```
T_List:=@DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; "Local"; "DBintro";"testview"; 1);
T_List:=@Sort(T_List; [DESCENDING]);
@if(@Iserror(T_List);
  1;
  @Subset(T_List;1)+1
);
```

Comment: Hi - where does that error occor ?  And when - is it when creating a new document or opening an existing one ?

Comment: It comes when I'm starting IBM notes(preview ) @user2808054 I can't even open the preview

Comment: Bad formula. Should be a colon, not semi-colon between servername and filename. Of course, there is no server named "Local". You would just use "" for local. @DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; "":"DBintro";"testview"; 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set type of field "testid" to "Number"
Change formula to

```
_List:=@DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; ""; "testview"; 1);
@If(    @IsError(_List);
            1;
        _List = "";
            1;
            @Subset(_List; 1) + 1
)
```

Set column sort to "Descending"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps re-arranging the logic might help - try this in the formula for Id field. Make the field "Computed When Composed" (next to field typer in properties box - it means it only evaluates when the doc is first created, and remains the same after - saves detecting @IsNewDoc :-D ):

```
T_List:=@DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; "Local"; "DBintro";"testview"; 1);
@if(@Iserror(T_List);
  1;
  @Subset(T_List;1)
);
```

You don't have to worry about the id field returning itself if the doc isn't new, because the computed when composed field stops evaluating after 1st save.

Comment: I want to show the id in form itself, when i'm saving the form I want it to be pushed into DB along with other fields

Comment: Is the view "DBIntro" sorted descending on 1st column  ? You're getting the forst element in the list so it assumes this. Alternative would be to leave the view unsorted (most recent reated docs go on end of view) and do @Subset(T_List;-1) which gets the last element

Comment: I don't know whether it's in sorted or not, so I go for it :P

Answer (score 1):

Bad formula for your dbColumn. There should be a colon, not semi-colon between servername and filename. Of course, there is no server named "Local". You would just use "" for local. Also, the filename is the full filename - "DBintro.nsf", not "DBintro".

```
T_List:=@DbColumn("Notes":"NoCache"; "":"DBintro.nsf";"testview"; 1);
T_List:=@Sort(T_List; [DESCENDING]);
@if(@Iserror(T_List);
  1;
  @Subset(T_List;1)+1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the unique ID set as a text field because I have found that the formula has to be converted to a text value and not just the unique document id.

Comment: No , I think that's the reason, I'm getting always 1 . Can you help me to solve it?